# error syntax in insert into

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, oledb

as for my question, here's the freakin' code..

```
Dim txt() As String
Dim _updateFlag As Boolean

Public Sub save()
    Dim query = String.Empty
    If Not _updateFlag Then
        query = "INSERT INTO tblGPSRoutes(Time,Latitude,Longitude,Elevation,Accuracy,Bearing,Speed)"
        query &= " VALUES ('" & txt(0) & "','" & txt(1) & "','" & txt(2) & "','" & txt(3) & "','" & txt(4) & "','" & txt(5) & "','" & txt(6) & "')"
        databaseFunctions.ExecuteQuery(query)
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully.")
    Else
        query = String.Empty
        query = "UPDATE tblGPSRoutes SET Time = '" & txt(0) & "', Latitude = '" & txt(1) & "', Longitude = '" & txt(2) & "', Elevation = '" & txt(3) & "', Accuracy = '" & txt(4) & "', Bearing = '" & txt(5) & "', Speed = '" & txt(6) & "' WHERE ID = " & Integer.Parse(textbox1.Text)
        databaseFunctions.ExecuteQuery(query)
        MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully.")
    End If
End Sub
```

it was working in my other forms.. I just used it here, *changed* the values from `.Text` to values from an array.
I got the error from `Try Catch` "Syntax error in Insert Into statement"

Am I missing something?
BTW, I use OleDB
**UPDATE :** these are the values of the `RichTextBox.Split(","c)`
04T16:18:42Z,14.524379,121.000830,60.700001,25.000000,350.299988,11.750000
before doing `save()` I tried it out on a -

```
For each word in txt
    MessageBox.Show(word)
Next
```

its perfectly showing each of them separated. is my theory wrong?

Comment: It's possible one of the values [txt(n)] contains a single quote since you aren't using a parameterized query.

Comment: since we cant see where stuff goes into the array, one of them could be blank, null, nothing, contain reserved words, illegal characters or bad karma

Comment: updated it. please check

Comment: DEBUG! set a breakpoint on your completed query string, copy/paste it in SQL management studio or whatever tool you use and check what syntax error the db's talking about...

Comment: Stop putting literals in your SQL and use proper parameters!  Yes, is it quick and easy, but will cause you all sorts of problems.

Comment: sadly, I don't know how, can you give me a link where I can get a quick look? nevermind if its MSDN though

Comment: those values exist as distinct values in your camera class, so why put them in a text box, then parse them back?  Then, most of them are values (Latitude), so they may not need ticks...depends on how the DB is defined

Comment: strings need to be enclosed in a single quote. Numbers do not.

Answer (score 1):

I know parameterized queries take some more time to set up, but they will save you time in the end. Here is an example of how you would use them.

```
  Private Sub Insert()
    Dim connectionString = ""   ''your connection string
    Dim commandText = "INSERT INTO tblGPSRoutes([Time],Latitude,Longitude,Elevation,Accuracy,Bearing,Speed) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    Using cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
      Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(commandText, cnn)
        With cmd.Parameters
          '' since you are using OleDb the parameter names don't matter. 
          '' Just make sure they are entered in the same order as your sql   
          .AddWithValue("@Time", txt(0))                        
          .AddWithValue("@Latitude", txt(1))
          .AddWithValue("@Longitude", txt(2))
          .AddWithValue("@Elevation", txt(3))
          .AddWithValue("@Accuracy", txt(4))
          .AddWithValue("@Bearing", txt(5))
          .AddWithValue("@Speed", txt(6))
        End With

        Try
          cnn.Open()
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
          '' handle the exception
        End Try
      End Using
    End Using
  End Sub
```

Comment: the culprit here is the `Time`. Its a reserved word by MS Access.